# SAFELY overclock CPU and GPU (up performance on motherboard and graphic card)

Tags: memory, graphics-card, cpu, motherboard, overclocking

Ok look i'm a complete Mountain man. when it comes to this tec stuff i have no idea. I would like to up my performance on my gaming computer/ all around computer. Here are my specs Please only comment if you can tell me directly how to do this safely.

SPECS:

OPERATING SYSTEM: Microsoft windows 10 (64-bit)

MEMORY: 10GB

PROCESSOR: AMD FX(tm)-6120 Six-Core Processor

MOTHERBOARD: ASRock- 970 Extreme4

VIDEO CARDS: AMD Radeon R9 200 Series

MONITORS: 2269W

HARD DISK: SanDisk SDSA5GK-016G-1006 ATA Device (16.0 GB)

NETWORK CARD: Realtek PCLe GBE Family Controller

Please help me i'm running out of moonshine.

Comment: Why? Leaving it at defaults will probably work better & more reliably anyway, and odds are you wouldn't even notice the 10% performance difference while waiting for the network & drive access anyway. Safest is to not do it.

Comment: didn't really read the question did yea.?

Comment: Leave the settings alone, concentrate on the moonshine...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

‘Overclocking’ means ‘running it faster than it was designed for’. This doesn’t go into one sentence with ‘safely’, unfortunately, as it is just the opposite.

Overclocking means consciously endangering your hardware to squeeze out some extra speed - like running your car engine in the red zone.